# Android Studio - Error while Installing APKs

Tags: android, installation

Suddenly none of my projects can be installed to my phone. It worked fine until this moment. Everything needed in my phone is enabled, including debugging, also i checked if there is an old version of apk in my phone, i removed cache, cleaned and rebuild project, changed app version from 1 to 2, but this error is always showing up.

[Running project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlZfV.png)

[After clicking OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JVe5.png)

AVD is working correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try this Settings->Apps->your_apps-> then select Uninstall for all users. Try this and let me know

Comment: @NiteshMishra My app is mising there, so i can't unninstall it.

Comment: did you try running this on device and see whats happening>\

Comment: @NiteshMishra Yes, nothing visible is happening on device, so i can't do much more on phone. Installations works only with other phones.

Answer (score 0):

when you try to override version, a request dialog appears on screen of mobile and Android studio. you have to allow it. if not try to uninstall previous version on your phone then reinstall your app.